# can not create instance in a new compute node openstack-ansible?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

when I add a new compute node to OpenStack-ansible everything seems ok but any instance can't create on it

> NoValidHost: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts
>   available. : NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found. There are
>   not enough hosts available. 2019-09-02 07:33:22.273 192 WARNING
>   nova.scheduler.utils [req-f85f9433-9585-407d-902a-108e90d8aa7a
>   4831a71d258444ffb7a51491f45dfe05 4e537668e9eb44639c1075f6013e367d -
>   default default] [instance: 56160be3-4f0c-48b2-bd24-0c2ac2331372]
>   Setting instance to ERROR state.: NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host
>   was found. There are not enough hosts available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked my Iaas but unfortunately, my compoute server was down so I try to install it again then my problem is fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run [nova-manage](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/rocky/cli/nova-manage.html) to map the new host to the cell.

```
nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose
```

Not a hundred percent sure on how to do this with openstack-ansible, but basically you need to execute [this](https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible-os_nova/blob/bc372732b803766d4a30a8642558b684f6a649f9/tasks/nova_db_post_setup.yml#L21).

If you are unsure, make sure you ran [these](https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ansible/latest/admin/scale-environment.html#add-a-compute-host).

```
# cd /opt/openstack-ansible/playbooks
# openstack-ansible setup-hosts.yml --limit localhost,NEW_HOST_NAME
# ansible nova_all -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_local gather_subset="!all"'
# openstack-ansible setup-openstack.yml --limit localhost,NEW_HOST_NAME
```